# Severity of Stackdriver logs always INFO for .NET Core app deployed to GKE

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have deployed my ASP.NET Core application to GKE and I am now seeing output logged in Stackdriver. However for some reason all of the log entries have severity of INFO. It doesn't matter if it's exception log (with severity ERROR) or something else... everything is logged as INFO.

How can I instruct Stackdriver Logger to tag log entries from .NET Core application with appropriate severity types?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first things first, that configuration should be done inside the log generator of your .NET application, like this:

Sometimes the application logs have some (some times none) string, such as **stderr** or **stdout**, that Stackdriver reads as the severity, so you could add a "**Severity**" field to your logs with the proper value and, this way, Stackdriver would read it as you specify, check the values [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity).

or in the GKE cluster with Fluentd, you can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration) for that. Also [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd) could work.

In general your logs are missing the severity field or have other strings.