# Serilog- Add "severity" property to top level of LogEvent for GKE?

Tags: .net-core, google-kubernetes-engine, serilog, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'm using Serilog with the `Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter` formatter in a .NET Core app in GKE. I am logging to Console, which is read by a GKE Logging agent. The GKE logging agent expects a "severity" property at the **top level** of the Log Event: [GCP Cloud Logging LogEntry docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)

Because of this, all of my logs show up in GCP Logging with severity "Info", as the Serilog `Level` is found in the `jsonPayload` property of the LogEntry in GCP. Here is an example LogEntry as seen in Cloud Logging:

```
{
    insertId: "1cu507tg3by7sr1"
    jsonPayload: {
        Properties: {
            SpanId: "|a85df301-4585ee48ea1bc1d1."
            ParentId: ""
            ConnectionId: "0HM64G0TCF3RI"
            RequestPath: "/health/live"
            RequestId: "0HM64G0TCF3RI:00000001"
            TraceId: "a85df301-4585ee48ea1bc1d1"
            SourceContext: "CorrelationId.CorrelationIdMiddleware"
            EventId: {2}
        }
        Level: "Information"
        Timestamp: "2021-02-03T17:40:28.9343987+00:00"
        MessageTemplate: "No correlation ID was found in the request headers"
    }
    resource: {2}
    timestamp: "2021-02-03T17:40:28.934566174Z"
    severity: "INFO"
    labels: {3}
    logName: "projects/ah-cxp-common-gke-np-946/logs/stdout"
    receiveTimestamp: "2021-02-03T17:40:32.020942737Z"
}
```

My first thought was to add a "Severity" property using an Enricher:

```
class SeverityEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(
            propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Severity", LogEventLevel.Error));
    }
}
```

The generated log looks like this in GCP, and is still tagged as Info:

```
{
    insertId: "wqxvyhg43lbwf2"
    jsonPayload: {
        MessageTemplate: "test error!"
        Level: "Error"
        Properties: {
            severity: "Error"
        }
        Timestamp: "2021-02-03T18:25:32.6238842+00:00"
    }
    resource: {2}
    timestamp: "2021-02-03T18:25:32.623981268Z"
    severity: "INFO"
    labels: {3}
    logName: "projects/ah-cxp-common-gke-np-946/logs/stdout"
    receiveTimestamp: "2021-02-03T18:25:41.029632785Z"
}
```

**Is there any way in Serilog to add the "severity" property at the same level as "jsonPayload" instead of inside it? I suspect GCP would then pick it up and log the error type appropriately.**

As a last resort I could probably use a GCP Logging sink, but my current setup is much more convenient and performant with the GKE Logging Agent already existing.

Here's a relevant Stack Overflow post with no information or advice past what I already have, which is not enough to solve this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215700/severity-of-stackdriver-logs-always-info-for-net-core-app-deployed-to-gke)

Comment: Writing my own formatter seems to be the way to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information detailing the severity of each SeriLog to Stackdriver log level, the next table might also help you

| Serilog | Stackdriver |
| --- | --- |
| Verbose | Debug |
| Debug | Debug |
| Information | Info |
| Warning | Warning |
| Error | Error |
| Fatal | Critical |

The complete information can be found at the following link

https://github.com/manigandham/serilog-sinks-googlecloudlogging#log-level-mapping

I think this code could help you to make Stackdriver recognize the severity of the logs given by SeriLogs.

```js
  private static LogSeverity TranslateSeverity(LogEventLevel level) => level switch
        {
            LogEventLevel.Verbose => LogSeverity.Debug,
            LogEventLevel.Debug => LogSeverity.Debug,
            LogEventLevel.Information => LogSeverity.Info,
            LogEventLevel.Warning => LogSeverity.Warning,
            LogEventLevel.Error => LogSeverity.Error,
            LogEventLevel.Fatal => LogSeverity.Critical,
            _ => LogSeverity.Default
        };
```

I will leave the link to the complete code here

https://github.com/manigandham/serilog-sinks-googlecloudlogging/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.GoogleCloudLogging/GoogleCloudLoggingSink.cs#L251

Greetings!